# Prove that $\det(A A^T) = 0$ where $A$ is the incidence matrix of a directed graph

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, algebraic-graph-theory, directed-graphs

I would like to prove the following result about graphs:

> Given a node-incidence matrix $A$ of a directed graph, the determinant of $A A^T$ is $0$.

---

The element $a_{ij}$ of the incidence matrix $A$ is determined in the following way:

$a_{ij}=0$ if the node $i$ is not on edge $j$.

$a_{ij}=−1$ if the edge $j$ ends on node $i$.

$a_{ij}=1$  if the edge $j$ starts on node $i$.

---

Numerical example:

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

is the node-incidence matrix for the directed graph with three nodes $A,B,C$ with

$$ A \to C, \qquad A \to B, \qquad B \to C $$

Comment: Notice that every edge contributes to a start and an end. Can you conclude that $A$ is singular?

Comment: Hint: What can you say about the sum of all rows and what does this tell you about the rank of $A$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @AndreasLenz I see it now thanks! A*A.T has zero determinant because the columns/rows are linearly dependent vectors

Comment: $A A^T$ is just the [graph Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix), which is singular by definition

Comment: You can draw graphs using http://www.webgraphviz.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $e$ denote the all-ones (column-)vector $e = (1,1,\dots,1)$. Because the columns of $A$ each have sum $0$, we have
$$
A^T e = 0 \implies AA^Te = A(A^Te) = A(0) = 0.
$$
Thus, the matrix $AA^T$ has a non-trivial nullspace, which means that it is singular, which means that $\det(AA^T) = 0$, which is what we wanted.